# What is the best way to add and order to Doctrine Nested Set Trees?

Tags: doctrine, nested-sets

What is the best way to add a sense of order in Doctrine Nested Sets?

The documention contains several examples of how to get al the childeren of a specific node

```
$category->getNode()->getSiblings()
```

But how can I for example:

- change the position of the fourth sibling to the second position
- get only the second sibling
- add a sibling between the second and third child
  etc...

Do I have to manually add and ordercolumn to the model to do these operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the second previous sibling:

```
$anotherCategory = $category->getNode()->getPrevSibling()->getNode()->getPrevSibling();
```

To insert category in its place:

```
$category->getNode()->moveAsPrevSiblingOf($anotherCategory);
```

To add a new sibling between second and third child, you'd simply use `insertAsNextSiblingOf` instead of `moveAsPrevSiblingOf`.